# SQL Plus : insert into numeric values with single quotes around them gives error

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert, sqlplus, quotes

A colleague of mine has created an export with `INSERT INTO` queries using Oracle SQL Developer. This export has put single quotes around every value, not just VARCHARs.

So let's say we have a simple table containing these columns (among others):

```
SOME_TEXT      VARCHAR2(256 BYTE)
SOME_NUMBER    NUMBER(15,2)
```

The export has an `INSERT INTO` like this:

```
Insert into MY_TABLE (SOME_TEXT,SOME_NUMBER) values ('test text','123,45');
```

You may note two things about the decimal value (`'123,45'`):

- It has single quotes around it
- It has a comma instead of a dot (the database of my colleague is Dutch, and mine is English)

The second is easy to fix, I can insert it in Oracle SQL Developer like this:

```
-- dot as thousand separator, comma as decimal point
alter SESSION set NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '.,';

Insert into MY_TABLE (SOME_TEXT,SOME_NUMBER) values ('test text','123,45');
-- All other insert queries

alter SESSION set NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ',.';
```

Which works fine.
However, some of the `.sql` files are very big, and can't be opened in SQL Developer. So instead I want to use SQL Plus to execute the `.sql` files containing the insert-statements.

However, even when `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` is changed, I'm currently getting the following error in SQL Plus due to the single quotes around the numeric value:

```
SQL> @"C:\my\path\test_insert_statement.sql"
values ('test text','123,45')
                    *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

I see two possible solutions, but I don't know if either is possible:

1. Is there a way to allow single quotes around numeric values in SQL Plus for Oracle databases?
2. Or is there a way to export a database without single quotes for numeric values in Oracle SQL Developer (then I can let my colleague generate another `.sql` file)?

Comment: Just a remark... The format of numeric variables in computer languages have been standardised since Cobol was created in the late 1950s. Although there're certainly workarounds in many situations, using localised formats should really be restricted to end-user display.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I agree. I kinda hate it when someone has a Dutch application anyway. Not only due to these annoying format differences, but also because Dutch error-messages are plain useless when googling for them. EDIT: I was about to remove it from the question, but just realized that replacing the comma with a dot actually allows SQL Plus to insert it... I'll delete my question and will ask my colleague to create another export with dot instead of comma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use single quotes around a numeric value. The error has occurred due to the decimal point character. All you need to change the decimal point character which can be done, as you have shown, as given below.

```
SQL> create table tbl1(
SOME_TEXT      VARCHAR2(256 BYTE),
SOME_NUMBER    NUMBER(15,2)
);  2    3    4  

Table created.

SQL> alter SESSION set NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ',.';

Session altered.

SQL> Insert into tbl1 (SOME_TEXT,SOME_NUMBER) values ('test text','123,45');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from tbl1;

SOME_TEXT        SOME_NUMBER
-------------    -----------
test text        123,45
```

Comment: I was about to delete this question when I realized that inserting it with a dot and single quotes is working in SQL Plus, but since you've already answered it I'll accept it instead.

Comment: Ah, I now also see what I did wrong.. I used `alter SESSION set NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '.,';` to set it to comma instead of `,.`. I was expecting the first to be thousand separators and second to be comma, but it's the other way around.. It's working now, so thanks.